# Its possible to log all commands and their output to file? [cmd]

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging, cmd

I'm trying to create log of silent installation of the application script and I need to log command and output to log file.

This is how it look like - its part of my .cmd file.
For now I need to create variable for every line (SET SETUP_0X=), but this solution its not a best, because I could have more command to write.

```
SET LogPath=C:\Logs
SET LogFile=%LogPath%\App_Install.log 2>&1

call :Loguj --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
call :Loguj --------------------------------LOG-Install-START-------------------------------
call :Loguj --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ECHO. >>%LogFile%

:Commands
SET SETUP_01=App.exe /S
SET SETUP_02=regedit /s SomeReg.reg
SET SETUP_03=DIR
SET SETUP_04=...


(...)
(goto Installation)

:Installation
call :Loguj %SETUP_01%
%SETUP_01% >> %LogFile%

call :Loguj %SETUP_02%
%SETUP_02% >> %LogFile%

call :Loguj %SETUP_03%
%SETUP_03% >> %LogFile%

call :Loguj %SETUP_04%
%SETUP_04% >> %LogFile%



:Finishing
Do other commands, but don't log this.

ECHO. >>%LogFile%
call :Loguj --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
call :Loguj --------------------------------LOG-Install-STOP--------------------------------
call :Loguj --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So its possible to improve it to not create variables, but log all commands and output from step :Installation until step :Finishing to log file?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for /f` loop to iterate over the variables and put the whole thing into a code block to redirect all of the output in one go:

```
:Installation
(for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('set setup_') do (
  call :loguj %%a
  %%a
)) >> %LogFile% 2>&1
```

or without setting variables:

```
:Installation
(for  %%a in ("app.exe /s" "regedit /s somereg.reg" "dir" "...") do (
  call :loguj %%a
  %%~a
)) >> %LogFile% 2>&1
goto :eof
:loguj
echo --- %~1 ---
```

Note: if there are many commands, you may hit the `cmd` line limit.

You can write it a bit more readable:

```
:Installation
(for  %%a in (
   "app.exe /s"
   "regedit /s somereg.reg"
   "dir"
   "..."
  ) do (
    call :loguj %%a
    %%~a
)) > log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: Hello @Stephan. 

Thank you for your response. Your solution works only in half, because its logging only output. I'm struggling with put to log command + output from this command. 
So simplest example:
Log Line1:  DIR C:
Log Line2:  Output of above command

Comment: the first snippet does (I was lazy with the `:loguj` part with the second snippet). An alternative is to `echo on` before the opening `(` and changing  `for` to `@for` and `@echo off` afterwards.

Comment: You are right. This first option with I missed earlier almost works. I wrote almost, because when I have it all defined in one log file, then on CMD window I have then message "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" and in log only output is stored (without command), so I done small  "workaround" for this by create second log file and last row from your first snippet: ")) >> %LogPath%\App_Install_Details.log 2>&1"